# How to display the name of the agent. Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm new to laravel. I have created a foreign key. what I am trying to do is to display the name of the agents according to the agents_id which is the foreign key.  I can only display the agents_id. when I put "$rapport->agents_id->nom" it doesn't work. I have this error.

> ErrorException
> Attempt to read property "nom" on int (View: C:\wamp64\www\SET\resources\views\rapport\index.blade.php)

```php
namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Agent as ModelsAgent;
use App\Models\Rapport;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Agent extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

  protected $fillable = [ 'matricule', 'agents_id', 'nom', 'prenom', 'email' ];

  public function Agents() {
    return $this->hasMany(Rapport::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more code on your view and controller?

Comment: `laravel-5` or `laravel-8`, which is it?

Comment: `$rapport->agents_id->nom`: Your error is saying that `agents_id` is an `interger`, not an object that your can pull `->nom` from. Did you maybe mean `$rapport->agent->nom`? (or similar). That assumes you have a relationship setup between them.

Answer (score 0):

In model which is related to agent you need `agent` relation (for example belongsTo) and to get name (property in agent model) you need `$model->agent->nom`

Comment: First you have wrong name in relation. You need: `reports` as method name.

Comment: In `Report` model you need `agent` relation (belongsTo)